# How do I break apart a URL to its component parts in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have URLs of files of unknown length input into my batch script.

http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv

http://www.place.com/Folder/file2.xml

There is little to no consistency with them at all. I need a way using batch only (though calling powershell from within batch is an option) to break these into the full path and file name.

http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/

http://www.place.com/Folder/

file1.csv

file2.xml

I've seen ways of doing it in many other languages, but I'm limited to batch, and it's not one of my strong languages. I tried using a far /f loop with "delims=/", but it quits when it gets to //.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "url=http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv"

for %%a in ("%url%") do (
   set "urlPath=!url:%%~NXa=!"
   set "urlName=%%~NXa"
)
echo URL path: "%urlPath%"
echo URL name: "%urlName%"
```

Output:

```
URL path: "http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/"
URL name: "file1.csv"
```

Comment: This one does exactly what I want it today without making polyglot statements. Thank you.

Comment: Great approach, @Aacini, +1! I guess it will fail if the last part appears multiple times in the URL, for instance, `http://repo.com/file.csv/file.csv`...

Comment: ...a work-around was to append a character not allowed in URLs like `|` and remove it after the `for` loop, @Aacini;

Comment: How to get only host name from the URL? That is, only "Repository.com" in the above given URL.

Comment: @JayakumariArumugham: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=/" %%a in ("%url%") do set "host=%%a"`

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell you can cast URL strings to `System.Uri` class which provides extensive information about the URL and its structure. You may need to work out with [Uri.Segments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx) property as follows:

```
PS C:\> # get System.Uri object:
PS C:\> $uri = [uri]"http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv"
PS C:\> $uri


AbsolutePath   : /Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv
AbsoluteUri    : http://repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv
LocalPath      : /Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv
Authority      : repository.com
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : True
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv
Segments       : {/, Stuff/, Things/, Repo/...}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : repository.com
Port           : 80
Query          :
Fragment       :
Scheme         : http
OriginalString : http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv
DnsSafeHost    : repository.com
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : False
UserInfo       :



PS C:\> # get base URL without page name and query parameters:
PS C:\> $uri.Scheme + ":/" + $uri.Authority + (-join $uri.Segments[0..($uri.Segments.Length - 2)])
http:/repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/
PS C:\> # get page/file name:
PS C:\> $uri.Segments[-1]
file1.csv
```

Comment: This works in a powershell ise, but I cannot get it to work as powershell -command ($uri=[uri]"%url%"; $uri.Segments[-1];). I'm trying to integrate this into a batch solution that does the rest of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` and `SubString` methods of the string class.

e.g.

```
$filename = $url.split('/')[-1]
# $url.split('/') splits the url on the '/' character. [-1] takes the last part
$rest = $url.SubString(0, $url.Length - $filename.Length)
# The first parameter is the starting index of the substring, the second is the length.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
Set input=http://Repository.com/Stuff/Things/Repo/file1.csv
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
For %%A in ("%input%") do (
    Set url= %%~pA
    set url=!url:~2!
    Set fileName=%%~nxA
)
echo.URL is: %url%
echo.File Name is: %fileName%
ENDLOCAL
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the first pure batch solution, but the forward slashes get changed to backslashes, and the first set of two get changed to a single. That will mess up the rest of the script.